# Ошибка при установке Angular 2 на Ubuntu 14

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Использую [этот туториал](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) для начала работы с Angular 2.

```
node -v = v5.10.0
npm -v = 3.8.3
```

Команда `npm install` выполнилась с одним warning-ом

Команда `npm start` выдает следующее:

```
events.js:154
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: watch node_modules/systemjs/test/tests/reldynamic.js ENOSPC
[1]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
[1]     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)
[1]     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)
[1]     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/r/www/angular.loc/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
[1]     at setFsWatchListener (/home/r/www/angular.loc/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/r/www/angular.loc/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/r/www/angular.loc/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
[1]     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/r/www/angular.loc/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
[1]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
[1] 
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
[1] npm ERR!
[1]  argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
[1] npm ERR! node v5.10.0
[1] npm ERR!
[1]  npm  v3.8.3
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR!
[1]  angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
[1] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[1] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! not with npm itself.
[1] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[1] npm ERR!     lite-server
[1] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
[1] npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
[1] npm ERR!
[1]  Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[1] npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] 
[1] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[1] npm ERR!     /home/r/www/angular.loc/npm-debug.log
[1] npm run lite exited with code 1
[0] 12:15:59 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Страничка с ожидаемым сообщением появляется, но дальнейшая работа приостанавливается. Как исправить? Помогите.

Upd: исправляется исполнением команды с правами `sudo`, но это временное решение. На что ему прав не хватает?

Comment: `npm i lite-server` затем  `npm start`, попробуй. А вообще ошибка вроде из-за того, что lite-server ожидает какие то параметры. Надо смотреть доки

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев пробую ;)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` попробуй из ошибки на трекере https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/35 и тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Первая ссылка помогла, оформи ответ - я приму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка уже обсуждалась на трекерах `lite-server` и так же был на англоязычном stackoverflow.

**Ошибка лечится командой**

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Взято с
**git:** https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/35

Comment: ссылки в ответах запрещены. Просто перенесите ответ в этот форум, чтоб его можно было найти сразу здесь

Comment: Не совсем понял про "перенести в этот ответ форум"

Comment: ) напишите именно решение, вместо ссылки.

Comment: @Razzwan готово)